# Why an homogeneous inequality can be rewritten as another one?

Tags: homogeneous-equation

Consider the following homogeneous inequality

$$ A^{T}*P+PA\lt0, P > 0$$

where $A$ is a square given matrix. Since the inequality above is homogeneous, it can be rewriten as

$$A^{T}*P+PA<-I, P \geq I$$

Why is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If the dimension is $1$ the first pair of inequalitites is the same as $2AP<0, P>0$, while the second is $2AP<-1, P\geq 1$. If $A=-1$, the set of solutions of the first pair is $P>0$, while the second is $P>1$. They don't look equivalent. Is there anything else that is known?

Comment: Yes, 

1. The second inequality is non strictly, i.e. less than. \leq.

2. This afford is done with the objective to solve the lyapunov equation A^{T}*P +P*A+I = 0 (I is the identity) also.

3. This is valid not only for one dimension.

Comment: Something that holds in general should be true in the particular cases.